# RecyclerView не заполняется во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть активити, в контейнер вкладывается фрагмент с ViewPager, в котором также 3 фрагмента(таба),в одном из фрагментов (MainFragment.class) есть RecyclerView,сам RecyclerView отображается, но не заполняется данными. а в логах

> 12-04 14:31:01.800 14145-14145/com.newakkoff.justad E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping 
>   [ 12-04 14:31:02.018 14145:14261 D/]                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9dc3f040, tid 14261

Вот код MainFragment.class

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(new String[]{"test one", "test two", "test three", "test four", "test five", "test six", "test seven"}));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

}
```

Код Adaptera с вложенным ViewHoldero

```
public  class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView mCardView;
        TextView mTextView;

        MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
         mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Вот View с Recycler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/card_item"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

вот CardView для recycler

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp" >
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:elevation="14dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </TextView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### UPDATE 1

код ViewPagerFragment.class

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {


    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTableLayout;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);



        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_main);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity()));
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        mTableLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTableLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    }
}
```

Xml для  ViewPagerFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/view_pager_main"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp">
```

Comment: Попробуйте instantrun отключить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб К сожалению все также

Comment: Ошибок кроме нулевой ширины RecyclerView не видно. Наверное в этом дело. А вообще - фрагмент во фрагменте - так себе идея.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб На самом деле слышал что чем меньше активити в приложении тем лучше, поэтому и хотел все во фрагментах сделать, может как то связвно с CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Мнения разные есть. И это было бы справедливо, если бы фрагменты работали нормально. К сожалению они работают так, что есть множество библиотек, которые позволяют делать то, для чего предназначены фрагмент но без самих фрагментов. Так что лучше уж актвити плодить - они гораздо стабильнее фрагментов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я вас понял, спасибо.

Comment: У вас до сих пор не работает? Вы убрали нулевую ширину у RecyclerView? высота, кстати, тоже нулевая у вас. И попробуйте убрать ConstraintLayout - может в нём проблема

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ставил match_parent, все также

Comment: Для высоты и ширины и пробовали ConstraintLayout брать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да менял на RelativeLayout, не помогает

Comment: А нету ли где-то выше в иерархии ScrollView? Если да - попробуйте убрать/заменить на NestedScrollView. Также попробуйте задать жёсткие размеры для RecyclerView. Ещё можно попробовать в onResume адаптер назначить. Ну и попробовать без ViewPager всё это отобразить. По коду у вас всё, вроде, верно - ошибка прячется где-то в непоказанном коде

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да при отображении без ViewPager все работает

Comment: Значит проблема в последнем. Если фрагмент добавляется, то, наверное, у ViewPager неподходящие размеры... Может тоже нулевые?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код фрагмента с viewPagerom там тоже менял Constraint на Relative, ширину высоту на match_parent, без изменений

Comment: Ну, магия какая-то. Единственное что вам остаётся - с нуля попробовать всё это написать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб :D, видимо придется пробовать, большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему, унаследовал адаптер ViewPagera не от

> PagerAdapter

, а от

> FragmentStatePagerAdapter

получилось вроде этого

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

List<PageModel> mPageModels= new ArrayList<>();

public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mPageModels.add(new PageModel(new MainFragment(), "Main"));
    mPageModels.add(new PageModel(new SendFragment(), "Send"));

}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return mPageModels.get(0).getFragment();
        case 1:
            return mPageModels.get(1).getFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return mPageModels.get(0).getTitle();
        case 1:
            return mPageModels.get(1).getTitle();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPageModels.size();
}
```